# JavaScript Adding Numbers through Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration, addition

I'm trying to find the sum of all elements in an array, but it's not working.

```js
var nums = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var num;

for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
  num += parseInt(nums[i]);
}
alert(num);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `nums.length` is `4`, the indexes run from `0` to `3`. `i <= nums.length` should be `i < nums.length`. The last iteration is accessing outside the array, so it's adding `undefined`, which results in `NaN`.

You also need to initialize `num` to `0`.

And there's no need to call `parseInt()` when the array contains integers.

```js
var nums = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var num = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  num += nums[i];
}
alert(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Array.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to calculate the sum

```
var nums = [10,20,30,40]; 
var num=nums.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
 alert(num);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/x5bkfcta/)

Answer (score 0):

first issue here, you `num` is undefined, the second is arrays are 0 indexed therefore `i =< nums.length` in your loop will return undefined for its last iteration

```js
var nums = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var num =  0;

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  num += parseInt(nums[i]);
}
alert(num);
```

Comment: Thank you Mugiwara